# Xamarin Retaining old copy of SQLITE DB after restarting app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am working on a cross-platform app with a Sqlite DB. However, it only seems to retain an older copy of the db. If I go into the app, re-download the DB, which is supposed to delete the old one and replace it with more current info. It seems to work, everything looks correct. However, when I close the app and restart it, the old DB info is back with no record of the new data that was downloaded minutes ago.

This is the routine used to clear the old data.

```
public Task<int> ClearTableAsync<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return database.ExecuteAsync("DELETE FROM "+ typeof(T).Name);
    }
```

The DB stored on the device is just a copy of a centrally stored DB. How do I make the newly stored info permanent?

Comment: Are you embedding a copy in your app?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call SaveChanges? May be you just work in memory and you must commit the transaction/operation on physically db file.